# How to get a website at a specific server IP in cdn with HTTPS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, python-requests, cdn

A website uses cdn, so ip of its domain name resolved by the DNS in different locations is different. I want to check the content of this website on each server to see if if the sync is all done.

For example, I want check http://www.a.com/index.html. Normally I should use: requests.get('http://www.a.com/index.html"), but then I can't specify a specific cdn serve to get. So I changed the www.a.com in the link to ip 1.2.3.4, and added the "HOST" on the header to implement SNI, so my python3.6 program look like this:

```
import requests
html = requests.get (url = "http://1.2.3.4/index.html", headers = {"Host": "www.a.com"})
```

It worked very well and I got the results I wanted. But while I do the same work for https://www.a.com/index.html, I will get an error:

```
import requests
html = requests.get (url = "https://1.2.3.4/index.html", headers = {"Host": "www.a.com"}, verify = False)

output:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool (host = '1.2.3.4', port = 443): Max retries exceeded with url: /index.html (Caused by SSLError (SSLError (1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c: 852) '),))
```

How can I do? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the certificate verification.

Download the certificate from the website and do `r = requests.get('https://...', , verify=True, cert=['/path/to/my/ca.crt'])`

You'll also want to [check if your certificates are valid](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v1.1.0/user/advanced/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I explored the website's cert file from chrome in Base64 and DER format. But all of them not working in cert="cert path". And, could you explain why "verify = False" not working? Mostly they work fine.  Thanks